# Should I use YouTube API to develop my subscription based services?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, firebase-hosting

I'm building a website that will eventually host educational how-to videos that intend to charge for via subscription based services.  I am using Firebase and have done some research for the best ways to do this.

I've come to the conclusion that hosting videos on your own storage isn't trivial and cost efficient.  So my question is if using YouTube's API is the right choice?

Here are my pros and cons:

PROS

- Leverage YouTube's storage
- Better user experience
- Option to leverage YouTube platform for views, user signups, traffic, etc

CONS

- Need to have users authenticate with YouTube
- Privacy of content will be able to be set in two different places (on website thru api, on youtube).
- Less reputable business if not hosting own content

I looked around and did not see sites using YouTube in such a way.  Obviously if successful the end solution should be in-house, but prior to that it seems like going with YouTube API for a startup is a better choice.

Comment: "This question is seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."

Comment: Fair enough - but just to be clear recommendations for any of those wouldn't really solve my problem.  What I need to know is whether going forward with the implementation of the YouTube API vs my own solution with Firebase is the smart choice from both an engineering and business perspective.

Comment: You're asking for a recommendation for something else but code that you're sharing with us, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow for the reason outlined. You seem to have a pretty good list of pros and cons, so are in a better position to choose than most folks. If you want to hear from other people's experience, there are better sites for that such as quora, or reddit.